# Symfony website with dynamic content (loaded from the database) in the navigation

Tags: php, symfony, twig

The website I'm working on has a navigation menu item called categories which is a drop-down containing some entries from the db (the users can adjust the categories from the admin panel.) The navigation is located in a `base.html.twig` file which is extended by all other twig files.

Question: What's the best way to get those entries? The only way that comes to my mind is use a call to `{{ render(controller(...)) }}` which would create a new request, what's a little overkill in my opinion and will slow the page in general down. Is there a better way to do it? Maybe an event which is called on every request and is able to transfer data to the view file?

Comment: The Twig `render()` extension won't create a new request, but it will internally call the controller and render its output into your template. The performance hit would be negligible. How is it overkill? Your idea actually sounds worse than the `render()` idea.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the Twig `render()` function. But how would an event listener be worse? The template is anyway used on each page, so on every request. Maybe a beginner question, but I'm not very experienced in the Symfony framework :(

Comment: Could someone please explain the down vote? In how far was this a bad question? Since I haven't found an answer searching Google, I asked it. I explained the situation and said what I try to use, asking if It's the right way. @sjagr explained, that the render function won't create a new request but reuses the existing and just create an instance of a new controller and call a function on that one and Raphaël explained nicely all possibilities, gave his opinion and a hint to further improve it. For me this helped a lot, so how is it a bad question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two good options to achieve this :

1. Use render() in your twig template to call a specific method from a controller (as you said in your message)
2. Create a twig extension to render your menu, it's very simple : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

In my opinion you should use the first option (a controller), since you only need to render your menu 1 time. Twig extension are better designed to be reused in several templates.

About your performance concern, don't worry, all you need is to cache your menu since it won't change often, and invalid the cache when the menu is updated in your backoffice.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the two options. In this case I'll use the first one. About the caching: Is there a build in cache in symfony I could use, or do I need an additional bundle for it? Do you have a link where the caching you're talking about is described?

Comment: There is no built-in cache class, it's up to you to cache the way you want, because there are tons of way to do it. You can use memcache, redis, apc, a file cache, etc.. Or you can use a basic file cache. You can also take a look on the HTTP cache : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html